# Can Get MongoDB Cursor from Cursor id?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I used Pymongo and i knew that Mongodb Cursors have their own id.
ex Pymongo) c.cursor_id

Then Can Get MongoDB Cursor from Cursor id ?

If it is impossible, To use the cursors not until timeout, Only Do I store in hardware(memory) that Loaded cursors?

Comment: Hi, could you elaborate what you're trying to achieve by retrieving the cursor ?

Comment: @Wan Bachtiar I want to make pagination API with cursor, Like elasticsearch "Scroll" , scroll = elasticsearch.Scroll(scroll_id)

Comment: I would suggest to use range queries for pagination https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/#using-range-queries